# Полноэкранное приложение с автозапуском и фокусом на себя

Tags: java, android

Подскажите какими методами можно сделать приложение которое будет запускаться при старте системы в полноэкранном режиме, и не будет давать возможности пользователю свернуть его.

Comment: А можно узнать цель написания такого приложения? Первое, что приходит в голову при прочтении вашего описания - вирус-вымогатель. Не уверен, что здесь найдутся люди, желающие способствовать написанию подобных программ.

Comment: @fori1ton. Нет) просто хочу сделать чтобы функционал устройства ограничивался приложением. Это будет что-то типа фоторамки-календарая и остальной функционал не нужен просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут подойдет вариант с лаунчером.

**1)** нужно сделать приложение full screen. Есть два варианта: через тему в манифесте либо в коде самой активити.
**2)** сделать приложение лаунчером, тогда его нельзя свенуть по нажатию на кнопку home. Тут только через манфест.

Поиск примеров предлагаю сделать самостоятельно, потому что находятся и применяются они довольно таки быстро и просто.

Comment: Спасибо, просто не совсем понимал как сформулировать запрос в гугле. Теперь более ясно куда копать.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать кастомную android custom firmware или ROM

Comment: Вообще я думал просто написать сервис который следит за тем чтобы приложение было открыто постоянно, но не хочу изобретать велосипед

Comment: Если этого достаточно, то, конечно, сервис будет более простой способ.